# Ошибка при вызове функции (Operand should contain 1 column(s))

Tags: mysql, sql

### Столкнулся с проблемой.  Не могу вызвать процедуру, потому что выдаёт ошибку

### Operand should contain 1 column(s)

В чем может быть проблема?
Вот функция:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION ReturnHours (id INT)
RETURNS INT

BEGIN
    DECLARE a int; DECLARE b int; DECLARE result int;
    SET a = (SELECT ПРЕДМЕТЫ.`Колво_лекций` FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ JOIN ПРЕДМЕТЫ WHERE ПРЕДМЕТЫ.ID=VAR_ID AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`ID_предмета`= VAR_ID);
    SET b = (SELECT ПРЕДМЕТЫ.`Колво_практик` FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ JOIN ПРЕДМЕТЫ WHERE ПРЕДМЕТЫ.ID = VAR_ID AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`ID_предмета`= VAR_ID);
    SET result = (SELECT @a+@b FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ where ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Лекции`=1 AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Практики`=1 );
    SET result = (SELECT @a FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ where ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Лекции`=1 AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Практики`=0);
    SET result = (SELECT @b FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ where ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Лекции`=0 AND ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.`Практики`=1);

RETURN result;
END//
```

Вот процедура:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE TheMostHours ()
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 

BEGIN
 DECLARE max_id int;
 DECLARE a int;
 DECLARE i int; SET i=0;
 SET max_id = (SELECT MAX(ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.ID) FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ); #количество итераций цикла
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE (ID int primary key not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ФИО nvarchar(100) not null,
 Колво_часов int not null DEFAULT 0
 );
 Label: WHILE i < max_id
 DO INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE(ФИО, Колво_часов) SELECT (SELECT ФИО FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ WHERE ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.ID = i, SELECT ReturnHours(i));
 i = i + 1;
 END WHILE Label;
 SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE TEMP_TABLE.Колво_часов = MAX(TEMP_TABLE.Колво_часов);
END//
```

Comment: SELECT * **FROM** TEMP_TABLE WHERE TEMP_TABLE.Колво_часов = MAX(TEMP_TABLE.Колво_часов) **FROM** TEMP_TABLE;
Точно 2 раза FROM ?

Comment: до туда не доходит компилятор , но все равно спасибо, не видел эту ошибку

Comment: DO INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE(ФИО, Колво_часов) SELECT **(SELECT ФИО FROM ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ WHERE ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ.ID = i, SELECT ReturnHours(i))**;
Вот тут вторая ошибка. Что по вашему такое (Select *, Select *) ? Так нельзя =) или так ((Select *),(Select *)) или вот так (Select *),(Select *) =)

Comment: Окей, теперь все компилируется, но при вызове процедуры выдает ошибку: Operand should contain 1 column(s)